# Celcius to fahrenheit with pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

So I just learned about pointers and how to make programs with separate functions in C. I made this fahrenheit to celcius program but my compiler gives me an error: "invalid use of void expression" in my printf's.

I know it's something to do with my function fahrenheit_temperature. But I don't see how to fix it? I've tried to change the function to double but it's not working. Any ideas? Thanks.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fahrenheit_temperature(double celcius_temp, double *fahrenheit_temp){
  *fahrenheit_temp = (9.0 / 5.0) * celcius_temp + 32.0;
}

int main(void){
  double fahrenheit_temp;

printf("Freezing point: %6.2f F.\n", 
     fahrenheit_temperature(0.0, &fahrenheit_temp));

printf("Boiling point: %6.2f F.\n",
     fahrenheit_temperature(100.0, &fahrenheit_temp));

return 0;
}
```

New code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fahrenheit_temperature(double celcius_temp, double *fahrenheit_temp){
  *fahrenheit_temp = (9.0 / 5.0) * celcius_temp + 32.0;
}

int main(void){
double fahrenheit_temp, celcius_temp;

printf("Enter degrees celcius: ");
scanf("%lf", &celcius_temp);
fahrenheit_temperature(celcius_temp, &fahrenheit_temp);
printf("The converted temperature is: %f\n", fahrenheit_temp);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: That looks much better, and you ARE in fact using the pointer properly in your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a variable, so use the variable in printf like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fahrenheit_temperature(double celcius_temp, double *fahrenheit_temp){
  *fahrenheit_temp = (9.0 / 5.0) * celcius_temp + 32.0;
}

int main(void){
  double fahrenheit_temp;

fahrenheit_temperature(0.0, &fahrenheit_temp);
printf("Freezing point: %6.2f F.\n",fahrenheit_temp);

fahrenheit_temperature(100.0, &fahrenheit_temp);
printf("Boiling point: %6.2f F.\n",fahrenheit_temp);

return 0;
}
```

Then you do not need to change the return type of your function fahrenheit_temperature, but just keep the function OUT of the printf statement - as it does not return any value.

Answer (score 3):

`fahrenheit_temperature()` is declared `void` so it does not return anything, following this nothing is passed to `printf()`.

Print the variable `fahrenheit_temp` after `fahrenheit_temperature()` returned. Pass `fahrenheit_temp` to `printf()` instead of `fahrenheit_temperature`.

You then can use the return value of the function to indicate failures/misuse.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define TEMP_C__TO__TEMP_F (temp_c) \
  ((9.0 / 5.0) * (temp_c) + 32.0)

#define ABSOLUTE_ZERO_TEMP_C (-273.15)
#define ABSOLUTE_ZERO_TEMP_F TEMP_C__TO__TEMP_F(ABSOLUTE_ZERO_TEMP_C)
#define INVALID_TEMP_F (ABSOLUTE_ZERO_TEMP_F - 1.)

int fahrenheit_temperature(double celcius_temp, double *fahrenheit_temp) 
{
  int result = 0;

  if (NULL == fahrenheit_temp)
  {
    result = -1;
    errno = EINVAL;
  }
  else if (ABSOLUTE_ZERO_TEMP_C > celcius_temp) /* It cannot be colder then −273.15 C. */
  {
    result = -1;
    errno = EINVAL;
  }
  else
  {
    *fahrenheit_temp = ABSOLUTE_ZERO_TEMP_C(celcius_temp);
  }

  return result;
}

int main(void)
{
  double fahrenheit_temp = INVALID_TEMP_F;

  if (-1 == fahrenheit_temperature(0.0, &fahrenheit_temp))
  {
    perror("fahrenheit_temperature() failed");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Freezing point: %6.2f F.\n", fahrenheit_temp);
  }

  /* Test error case 1: */
  fahrenheit_temp = INVALID_TEMP_F;
  if (-1 == fahrenheit_temperature(0.0, -543.21))
  {
    perror("fahrenheit_temperature() failed");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Test 1 failed: invalid value, should not get here: %6.2f F.\n", fahrenheit_temp);
  }

  /* Test error case 2: */
  fahrenheit_temp = INVALID_TEMP_F;
  if (-1 == fahrenheit_temperature(0.0, NULL))
  {
    perror("fahrenheit_temperature() failed");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Test 2 failed: invalid value, should not get here: %6.2f F.\n", fahrenheit_temp);
  }

  ...
```

:-)

Comment: I don't want to return the result in the fahrenheit_temperature function because I want to use pointers :)

But I've tried to implement what you suggest in the main (I think):

Is this better?

Answer (score 1):

`fahrenheit_temperature` returns `void` so `printf` is being passed `void`, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to pass a value to `printf`. Now you are passinge `void` through the called function.

A possible minimal fix is adding `return *fahrenheit_temp;`

```
#include <stdio.h>

double fahrenheit_temperature(double celcius_temp, double *fahrenheit_temp){
    *fahrenheit_temp = (9.0 / 5.0) * celcius_temp + 32.0;
    return *fahrenheit_temp;
}

int main(void){
   double fahrenheit_temp;

   printf("Freezing point: %6.2f F.\n", 
       fahrenheit_temperature(0.0, &fahrenheit_temp));

   printf("Boiling point: %6.2f F.\n",
       fahrenheit_temperature(100.0, &fahrenheit_temp));

   return 0;
}
```

Alternatively you may prefer to use the stored value in the local variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double fahrenheit_temperature(double celcius_temp, double *fahrenheit_temp){
    *fahrenheit_temp = (9.0 / 5.0) * celcius_temp + 32.0;
    return *fahrenheit_temp;
}

int main(void){

    double fahrenheit_temp;
    fahrenheit_temperature(0.0, &fahrenheit_temp);
    printf("Freezing point: %6.2f F.\n", fahrenheit_temp);

    fahrenheit_temperature(100.0, &fahrenheit_temp);
    printf("Boiling point: %6.2f F.\n", fahrenheit_temp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I've understood pointers correctly I'd say the return in fahrenheit_temperature function unnecessary. Is that wrong?

Comment: It is a question of personal preferences and performances. You may prefer the second solution. However, I posted both solutions since you are learning about pointers..